Windows different scaling on multimonitor setup
I have a notebook (I think its 14") with a 1920x1080 resolution. Clearly things are too small and in the settings I have set a 125% resize in the screen option (and also a text size increase).
The issue is that I have another external old monitor of 19" with a resolution of 1280x1024.
The problem is that with 125% resize things are good on the notebook display but becomes too big on the external monitor. I can't use a smaller resizing otherwise on the notebook things get too small.
Any Idea on how to solve this?
notebook (good sizing with 125%):

External monitor (too big with 125%):

Edit
Nevermind I was able to set differnet scaling level for the different monitors. Now it works.
Before it was not working because I also resied the font size in accessibility settings, and that applies to both monitor.

Hi giò, you can add your solution as an answer to your own question and check mark it as answered. This helps out the community members who have the same problem in future.
